# "it's understood" as phrase

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

After I heard it twice in song lyrics ("Californication","The Adultress"): Is this a standing phrase? And while I have an approximate feeling what it means (almost "it's an axiom") - what is the *exact* meaning?

Comment: The passive form ***It's understood** [that some assertion is true]* means ***Everyone knows** [that it's true]* - often with the implication that ***it goes without saying*** (i.e. - people just *know* that it's true without needing to be told, or to discuss it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Agreed, however it is almost always used without any citation or justification and the underlying idea is often "it's my opinion".

Comment: @PeterJennings: I can't accept that. Sure, *occasionally* a speaker might mean ***I** know that*, but nearly always it means ***anyone** would know that.* Perhaps with the caveat *...if they were aware of the full context within which we are speaking.* And it's very rarely ***I think** that...* Perhaps you're conflating with ***It's my understanding that...***

Comment: @FumbleFingers Could we agree that it is ambiguous and depends on context? For example **it's understood that grass is green** is undoubtedly true (in most circumstances) but **it's understood that John is a thief** may be true or the beginnings of a slanderous lie.

Comment: @PeterJennings I think in the sentence "it's understood that John is a thief" implies(The speaker is not sure, but think/know it to be the case, because he has been said so.

Comment: I recommend Google; it offers several explanations of this phrase as top hits.

Comment: @PeterJennings: That's pushing it. Longman Dictionary: [**be understood (that)**](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-understood-that) (formal) *if something is **understood**, everyone knows it, **or has agreed to it**, and there is no need to discuss it.*